# Joomla! Multiple modules assignment

Tags: joomla, module, menu, joomla-extensions

I'm looking for an extension or a way to assign many modules at the same time without having to open each module. This could work like that:

a. Link modules directly from menu manager to menu items

b. Categorize modules so that you could manage their position, assignment, style as a category that would affect all related modules

c. A simple extension for the "batch" in module manager that would control not only the position, but the menu assignment as well

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show how you've tried to solve the problem yourself before asking for help. Stack Overflow is a [Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) site, not a discussion site.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problems in part with different template solutions and then different assignment of menu voices to this templates.